# Without using Mutex class i have to write log in xml file of different aplications

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, multithreading

```
public void WriteXmlLog(string logType, string logFlag, string logModule, string logLocation, string logText, string logStackTrace)
    {
        Mutex objMutex = new Mutex(false, @"Global\MySharedLog");
        objMutex.WaitOne();
        try
        {
            if(!File.Exists(_logFilePath))
            {
                File.WriteAllText(_logFilePath, "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes'?>\r\n <AppXmlLogWritter></AppXmlLogWritter>");
            }

            string currentDateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

            xmlDoc.Load(_logFilePath);
            XmlElement newelement = xmlDoc.CreateElement("LogData");
            XmlElement xmlLogID = xmlDoc.CreateElement("LogID");
            XmlElement xmlLogDateTime = xmlDoc.CreateElement("LogDateTime");
            XmlElement xmlLogType = xmlDoc.CreateElement("LogType");
            XmlElement xmlLogFlag = xmlDoc.CreateElement("LogFlag");
            XmlElement xmlLogApplication = xmlDoc.CreateElement("LogApplication");
            XmlElement xmlLogModule = xmlDoc.CreateElement("LogModule");
            XmlElement xmlLogLocation = xmlDoc.CreateElement("LogLocation");
            XmlElement xmlLogText = xmlDoc.CreateElement("LogText");
            XmlElement xmlLogStackTrace = xmlDoc.CreateElement("LogStackTrace");

            xmlLogID.InnerText = _logIDPrefix + currentDateTime + randomNumber;
            xmlLogDateTime.InnerText = currentDateTime;
            xmlLogType.InnerText = ((LogTypes)Convert.ToInt32(logType)).ToString();
            xmlLogFlag.InnerText = logFlag;
            xmlLogApplication.InnerText = _logApplication;
            xmlLogModule.InnerText = logModule;
            xmlLogLocation.InnerText = logLocation;
            xmlLogText.InnerText = logText;
            xmlLogStackTrace.InnerText = logStackTrace;

            newelement.AppendChild(xmlLogID);
            newelement.AppendChild(xmlLogDateTime);
            newelement.AppendChild(xmlLogType);
            newelement.AppendChild(xmlLogFlag);
            newelement.AppendChild(xmlLogApplication);
            newelement.AppendChild(xmlLogModule);
            newelement.AppendChild(xmlLogLocation);
            newelement.AppendChild(xmlLogText);

            xmlDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(newelement);
            xmlDoc.Save(_logFilePath);

        }
        finally
        {
            objMutex.ReleaseMutex();
        }
    }
```

I am writing logs in xml file of several different applications.
        see below code i m using Mutex class for locking purpose Means when two thread comes at a time mutex.waitone() method wouldn't release second thread if first thread doing task.
         Is it possible without using Mutex class i have to write log in xml file of different aplications

Answer (score 2):

`Mutex` is a standard technique to synchronize access to a shared resource across multiple processes. If it was concurrent access within the same process you could have used more lightweight classes such as [`ReaderWriterLockSlim`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.aspx). But since you need to support cross process synchronizations Mutexes is the way to go.

Or maybe start asking yourself whether writing logs to a text file is appropriate in this case. Have you considered logging to the EventLog which will handle concurrency for you? Have you considered logging to a shared database which also will handle the concurrency for you?

By the way have you considered using a logging library to perform your logging instead of manually doing it with some `XmlDocument`? .NET already has built-in tracing capabilities. Maybe you should explore them before rolling such custom solutions.

Many questions you should probably be asking yourself now.

Comment: Darin then what is the best way to share xml file for read/write purpose by different applications.

Comment: I thought I have already answered this. Read the first sentence of my answer once again - `Mutexes` is the way to go.

Comment: using filestream is possible darin

Comment: using(FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(_logFilePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite))
   {